# Differences between indention options

Tags: vimrc, indentation, options

I have read `'ai'`, `'si'`, `'cin'`, `'ci'`  help pages in Vim but I still cannot realize that what indention option is good for me.

Yes, I can read that :help pages again and set whatever I need in my vimrc but can I use all of the above indention options in my vimrc?

I mean, **if I set them step by step, will vim conflict the options together and cause trouble in each indention?**

Also I have found that setting `'si'` has no effect when `'cin'` is present and setting `'ci'` isn't recommended when `'ai'` is present. **Is it true?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `:h indent.txt`:

```
There are in fact four main methods available for indentation, each one
overrides the previous if it is enabled, or non-empty for 'indentexpr':
'autoindent'    uses the indent from the previous line.
'smartindent'   is like 'autoindent' but also recognizes some C syntax to
        increase/reduce the indent where appropriate.
'cindent'   Works more cleverly than the other two and is configurable to
        different indenting styles.
'indentexpr'    The most flexible of all: Evaluates an expression to compute
        the indent of a line.  When non-empty this method overrides
        the other ones.  See |indent-expression|.
```

So the 4 indent types are `'autoindent'`, `'smartindent'`, `'cindent'`, and `'indentexpr'`.

> I can ... set whatever I need in my vimrc but can I use all of the above indention options in my vimrc?

Indention settings are local to a buffer. Typically when you have `filetype plugin indent on` you get the default indent setting for the `'filetype'`. If you want to change the indent settings for a file type I would recommend you add your changes to `~/.vim/after/indent/<filetype>.vim`, e.g. `~/.vim/after/indent/c.vim`.

It is also worth looking through `:h indent.text` as some filetypes have special options which can change indention styles/preferences.

Comment: Thanks. So it would be better to just turn on `'cin'`, yes? & How about `'ci'`isn't a indention option?

Comment: C/C++ uses `'cindent'`, Python uses `'indexexpr`', and Lisp uses `'autoindent'`. Each filetype uses different indent settings to fit it's needs. `'copyindent'` - make `'autoindent'` use existing indent structure.